# Calculation in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

My HTML looks like that:

```html
<input type="text" id="qty">
<input type="text" id="unp">
<input type="text" id="tv">

<input type="text" id="qty2">
<input type="text" id="unp2">
<input type="text" id="tv2">

<input type="text" id="qty3">
<input type="text" id="unp3">
<input type="text" id="tv3">

...
```

How can I calculate `tv = qty*unp` and `tv2 = qty2*unp2`?

Comment: What have you tried so far ? Could you share the Javascript you have generated so far ?

Comment: function calculate() {
    
   
    var a = document.getElementById('qty').value; 
    var b = document.getElementById('unp').value;
    var c = document.getElementById('tv'); 
    var tva = a * b;
     c.value = tva;
}

Comment: if you group them inside of a span or something and added a class such as 'input-group' to each span you could get the amount of input groups with document.getElementsByClass then in a while loops do (qty+i)*(unp+i) etc...

Comment: @nicael your answer works well. Here is just another solution http://jsfiddle.net/s5s5xgLr/

Comment: Why did you accept [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29322341) answer, while it doesn't work at all?

Comment: I just put it , and it works well @nicael.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```js
function tvFunction() { 
       var inputTags = document.getElementsByTagName('INPUT');  
  for(var i=1; i<=inputTags.length ; i++){


        if(i == 1) 
        {
        var qty= document.getElementById('qty').value;
        var unp = document.getElementById('unp').value;
        var result= Number(qty)*Number(unp);
        document.getElementById('tv').value = result;
        }
     else 
     {
        var qty= document.getElementById('qty'+i).value;
        var unp = document.getElementById('unp'+i).value;
        var result= Number(qty)* Number(unp);
        document.getElementById('tv'+i).value = result;
     }
  }
  }
```

```html
     <input type="text" id="qty">
<input type="text" id="unp">
<input type="text" id="tv">


<input type="text" id="qty2">
<input type="text" id="unp2">
<input type="text" id="tv2">


<input type="text" id="qty3">
<input type="text" id="unp3">
<input type="text" id="tv3">

<input type="text" id="qty4">
<input type="text" id="unp4">
<input type="text" id="tv4">

<input type="text" id="qty5">
<input type="text" id="unp5">
<input type="text" id="tv5">

<input type="text" id="qty6">
<input type="text" id="unp6">
<input type="text" id="tv6">

<input type="text" id="qty7">
<input type="text" id="unp7">
<input type="text" id="tv7">

<input type="text" id="qty8">
<input type="text" id="unp8">
<input type="text" id="tv8">

    <input type="button" id="btn3"
           onclick="tvFunction()" value="Calculate">
```

Answer (score 2):

First, as tv* are result fields, disable them.

```
$("input[id^=tv]").attr('disabled','disabled');
```

Then:

```
$("input[id^=qty], input[id^=unp]").keyup(function(){
    var index = $(this).attr("id").replace("qty","").replace("unp","");
    $("#tv"+index).val(parseInt($("#qty"+index).val())*parseInt($("#unp"+index).val()))
    if($("#tv"+index).val()=="NaN"){$("#tv"+index).val("");}
})
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/2wjsjg5j/2/)

And yes, don't forget to import jQuery by adding

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

before your inputs.

Comment: When i try this on fiddle it works well, but in my testing project it doesn't working. What's the problem?

Answer (score 0):

You can easily get the values of your inputs like this:

```
document.getElementById('qty').value
```

and also set them like this:

```
document.getElementById('tv').value = 'Hi!';
```

So,  using this information, you are able to quite easily set the value of another input to the sum of two other inputs:

```
var qty = Number(document.getElementById('qty').value);
var unp = Number(document.getElementById('unp').value);
document.getElementById('tv').value = qty + unp;
```

`Number()` just turns a string into a number.

Example:

```js
document.getElementById('tv').onclick = function(){
  var qty = Number(document.getElementById('qty').value);
  var unp = Number(document.getElementById('unp').value);
  
  document.getElementById('tv').value = qty + unp;
};

document.getElementById('tv2').onclick = function(){
  var qty2 = Number(document.getElementById('qty2').value);
  var unp2 = Number(document.getElementById('unp2').value);
  
  document.getElementById('tv2').value = qty2 + unp2;
};
```

```html
<input type="text" id="qty">+
<input type="text" id="unp">=
<input type="text" id="tv" placeholder="Click me!">
<br>

<input type="text" id="qty2">+
<input type="text" id="unp2">=
<input type="text" id="tv2" placeholder="Click me!">
```

Comment: You're right, it's not; that's why I had voted up your better solution, because its so much more flexible. This one is still a viable solution though, I don't see why anyone would downvote it.

Answer (score -1):

Basic code :

```
var tv = document.getElementById("qty").value * 
document.getElementById("unp").value;

document.getElementById("tv").value = tv;

var tv2 = document.getElementById("qty2").value * 
document.getElementById("unp2").value
document.getElementById("tv2").value = tv2;
```

Comment: And are you going to add those functions for every row? tv3, then tv4, etc? No,  -1, that's a bad solution.